# Handle NumericUpDown.ValueChanged event before ToolStripButton.Click event

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, toolstripbutton

I have a form with the `NumericUpDown` and the `ToolStripButton`.

In the `NumericUpDown`s `ValueChanged` event handler the value of some object instance is changed.

In the `ToolStripButton`s `Click` event handler the object instance is saved.

Now the problem is that if I rewrite the value in the `NumericUpDown` and then click on the `ToolStripButton` to save the state the `ToolStripButton`s `Click` event is fired **before** the `NumericUpDown`s `ValueChanged` event so I first save the instance and after that I changed it.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Foo _foo = new Foo();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _foo.Value = numericUpDown1.Value;
    }

    private void ToolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _foo.Save();
    }

    private class Foo
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            //Save the value...
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to solve this?
Those events are fired in the correct order if I use the `Button` control, but not if I use the `ToolStripButton` control.

Comment: Overload `Foo.Save()`, so it accepts a decimal argument: `Foo.Save(decimal value);`. The original, parameter-less, `Foo.Save()` can just call `Save(this.Value)`. In `ToolStripButton1_Click` you can then call `Foo.Save(numericUpDown1.Value)`, so it will save the current, manually edited, value.

Comment: Well that is really interesting. So if I use the `numericUpDown1.Value` it will *refresh* its value and also immediately fires `ValueChanged` event so just after getting the `numericUpDown1.Value` I can also get the correct value from the `_foo.Value`.

Comment: Yes. Fetching the current value, the sequence of events will revert to standard behaviour, so `ValueChanged` is raised right after you get the edited value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, instead of `ValueChanged`, handle `Validated` event of `NumericUpDown` and also in the `Click` event handler of `ToolStripButton`, call `this.Validate()` before save:

```
private void NumericUpDown1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _foo.Value = numericUpDown1.Value;
}

private void ToolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    _foo.Save();
}
```

**Note:** If there are other controls on the form which may have `Validating` event and you may set `e.Cancel = true` for them, you need to check the result of `Validate` method before calling `Save`, using `if(this.Validate()){ /*...*/ }`.

Comment: This solution works. I already tried to call `Validate`, but only for `NumericUpDown` and it didn't work. Any idea why it works for the whole `Form`, but not for the specified control?

Comment: @Artholl My expectation is by calling `Validate` method of the `NumericUpdown` and handling `Validated` event, you get the same result; But I haven't tried that.